# Import data from Notepad to Excel and separate them in columns

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I have a lot of information misplaced on Excel 2013 as I imported them from a Notepad.

I would like to know if there is any formula which I can use to have all the email addresses to be moved on one column and from there is would be easy for me to manage the rest.

When I import data from Notepad to Excel, and separate them in column by space and get them in Excel as shown below:

```
Name, middle name last name, Email address, phone number
Name, last name, Email address, phone number
Name, middle late, another name, last name, Email address, phone number
```

As you can see above, information are mixed up and I would like to know how I can get to place all the email addresses found in any column and merge them all into a single one because now it takes too much time to go through all the information and do it manually.

Comment: You need to provide more information on what exactly you need. It would be better to provide an example if possible. Also mention what you have already tried and where exactly are you stuck

Comment: This question is lacking details needed for anyone to be able to help you. Please add details of what you have tried so far, any formulas you have tried and what research you have done. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Comment: sound like you have email address broken apart to multiple columns. You need a macro to combine information of a few columns into one. If so, there should be plenty of resources out there, including what you can find in Superuser. Please include information of your data for the community to better help you

Comment: Apologies if my questions wasn't very details, I will try again.
When I import data from notepad to excel, and separate them in column by space and get them in excel as below
Name, middle name last name, Email address, phone number
Name, last name, Email address, phone number
Name, middle late, another name, last name, Email address, phone number.

As you can see above, information are mixed up and I would like to know how I can get to place all the Email addresses found in any column and merge them all into a single one coz now it takes time to go through all the info & do it manually

Comment: The way to go about this would be to use `find()` to locate the `@` in the e-mail address, then search both left and right from the `@` for whitespace characters that mark the beginning and end of the e-mail address. (Is this enough to get you on track? I don't have enough battery left to code and test a full answer right now.)